# Date dialog Gets forceclose when it comes to December month

Tags: java, android, datepicker, forceclose

When i click on Dialog it gets Forceclose. works fine till November. but when i select December it gets forceclose. please see the code.

```
  // ---------------- For DatePicker ----------------
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        if(date.toString().length() > 0)
        {
            //12/31/1986
            cmonth =(Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0,2)));
            cday =(Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3,5)));
            cyear =(Integer.parseInt(date.substring(6,10)));
        }
        else
        {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        }
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            //return new DatePickerDialog(ProfileSetting.this, mDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth-1, cday); //Gets forceclose when it comes to December month
            return new DatePickerDialog(ProfileSetting.this, mDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth, cday); // works till November
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: try to use the commented line. i.e.  "return new DatePickerDialog(ProfileSetting.this, mDateSetListener, cyear, cmonth-1, cday);".

Comment: do post the exception stack, but reason could be calendar uses 0 -11 as months but DatePickerDialog uses either 0 -11 or 1-12 depending upon Locale

Comment: @Raj i have already used that commented line. but issue is same. so i removed -1 from month. but no solution.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(7680): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(7680): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.Etl/com.android.More.ProfileSetting}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(7680): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(7680):  at com.android.More.ProfileSetting.setAllDatailView(ProfileSetting.java:437)
E/AndroidRuntime(7680):  at com.android.More.ProfileSetting.onCreate(ProfileSetting.java:233)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thorough observation of your code pasted in Question, it was a mistake done by you.

in the first if loop of the `onCreateDialog()` you are getting the date in this format 12/31/1986. in which you are taking month as 12.

and in the else loop you take month directly from Calendar instance which will give you only upto 11.

So to work in both conditions you need to do decrement of month in first if loop.

Change your if loop as below

```
if(date.toString().length() > 0)
        {
            //12/31/1986
            cmonth =(Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0,2)));
            cmonth--;
            cday =(Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3,5)));
            cyear =(Integer.parseInt(date.substring(6,10)));
        }
```

Hope it will works for you.

Comment: Do not consider if condition.I have debug the code the fault is in else part.If condition gets date from server. while Else part prints Current date in Date Dialog. so when i debug in January month the value of cmonth is 0.

Comment: @RonakPandya Calendar instance will return January value as 0 and December values as 11. you have an idea about that?